# Symfony 5 project not installing with stof-doctrine-extensions

Tags: symfony, symfony5, stofdoctrineextensions

I try to create a new Symfony 5 project with doctrine extensions but it fails.
Here is the sequence :

```
$ symfony new myProject --full

$ cd myProject

$ composer require stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle ( as indicated in https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/installation.html#installation-using-symfony-flex )
```

And it results in :

```
Using version ^1.4 for stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "5.1.*"
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove doctrine/cache 1.10.2
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/cache 1.10.2
    - doctrine/common 2.2.1 conflicts with doctrine/cache[1.10.2].
    - doctrine/common 2.2.2 conflicts with doctrine/cache[1.10.2].
    - doctrine/common 2.2.3 conflicts with doctrine/cache[1.10.2].
    - doctrine/common 2.3.0 conflicts with doctrine/cache[1.10.2].
    - Installation request for doctrine/cache (locked at 1.10.2) -> satisfiable by doctrine/cache[1.10.2].
    - Installation request for stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle ^1.4 -> satisfiable by stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle[v1.4.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/common 3.0.2|install doctrine/common 2.2.1|install doctrine/common 2.2.2|install doctrine/common 2.2.3|install doctrine/common 2.3.0
    - Conclusion: remove doctrine/common 3.0.2|install doctrine/common 2.2.1|install doctrine/common 2.2.2|install doctrine/common 2.2.3|install doctrine/common 2.3.0
    - stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle v1.4.0 requires gedmo/doctrine-extensions ^2.3.4 -> satisfiable by gedmo/doctrine-extensions[v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.11, v2.4.12, v2.4.13, v2.4.14, v2.4.15, v2.4.16, v2.4.17, v2.4.18, v2.4.19, v2.4.2, v2.4.20, v2.4.21, v2.4.22, v2.4.23, v2.4.24, v2.4.25, v2.4.26, v2.4.27, v2.4.28, v2.4.29, v2.4.3, v2.4.30, v2.4.31, v2.4.32, v2.4.33, v2.4.34, v2.4.35, v2.4.36, v2.4.37, v2.4.38, v2.4.39, v2.4.4, v2.4.40, v2.4.41, v2.4.42, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.3.10 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.3.11 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.3.12 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.0 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.1 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.10 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.11 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.12 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.13 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.14 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.15 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.16 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.17 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.18 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.19 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.2 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.20 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.21 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.22 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.23 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.24 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.25 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.26 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.27 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.28 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.29 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.3 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.30 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.31 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.32 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.33 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.34 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.35 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.36 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.37 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.38 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.39 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.4 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.40 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.41 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.42 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.5 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.6 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.7 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.8 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.4.9 requires doctrine/common ~2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.3.4 requires doctrine/common >=2.2,<2.5-dev -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.3.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.3.5 requires doctrine/common >=2.2,<2.5-dev -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.3.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.3.6 requires doctrine/common >=2.2,<2.5-dev -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.3.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.3.7 requires doctrine/common >=2.2,<2.5-dev -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.3.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.3.8 requires doctrine/common >=2.2,<2.5-dev -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.3.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3].
    - gedmo/doctrine-extensions v2.3.9 requires doctrine/common >=2.2,<2.5-dev -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.3.0, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[2.12.0, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[2.13.0, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[2.13.1, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[2.13.2, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[2.13.3, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.11.0, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[2.2.0, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.10.0, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.4.0, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.4.1, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.4.2, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.4.3, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.5.0, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.5.1, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.5.2, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.5.3, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.6.0, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.6.1, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.6.2, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.7.0, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.7.1, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.7.2, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.7.3, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.8.0, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.8.1, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.9.0, 3.0.2].
    - Installation request for doctrine/common (locked at 3.0.2) -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[3.0.2].
```

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I've found it. Explanation is here [explanation and how to fix it](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-doctrine/sluggable#comment-5070272210)

The problem is that the orm pack installed by symfony myProject --full installs doctrine 3 but stof extensions work with doctrine 2.  So using doctrine 2 fix the error.

symfony composer require doctrine/common:^2.7 --update-with-dependencies